# Find top K most common locations for geo spatial data in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry, geospatial

We have user data which is geo spatial in nature (lat, long). We use SQL server to store this (geometry data type). Is there any implementation of getting a sense of top k most popular locations visited by a user (geo data). Say we take a radius of 100m and consider all the points within them to same location. This will basically mean clustering all the user locations and finding the most filled cluster.

Just like for scalar values, we do group by on a table to find out which entry occurs the most. How do i achieve this for geo data ?

Comment: If it's lat/long, why are you using `geometry` rather than `geography`?

Comment: Also, take an extremely absurd case where we store a series of points, each 90m apart, all the way around the equator (with whatever fudging is required to complete the circle if it's not precisely divisible by 90). Each point is within 90m of two other points but how do you decide where a cluster lies?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for the response. Yeah i thought about that, but for practical data points, like a user travelling around within a city, it is justified to think of few clusters getting formed around his home and office locations right ? we currently are solving this at compute level, but i was curios to know if there is way to solve it at database level.

Answer (score 0):

Geohashing can be used to solve this, which is a way to denote a region of the Earth with a hash. An efficient implementation of this is Google's S2 library.

Using S2 you would do something like:

1. Assign each point to a given S2 CellId representing a region (you can adjust it to different area levels ranging from [a face of the Earth to something smaller than your fingertip](https://s2geometry.io/resources/s2cell_statistics))
2. On retrieval, for a given point, convert that to a S2 CellId and break it down to S2 CellIds that are at the indexed level. Then fetch all "clusters" with a simple `SELECT * FROM points WHERE point.s2_cell_id IN $RETRIEVAL_IDS`

Here's a quick example of building an index with the [Node S2 library](https://github.com/radarlabs/s2):

```
const s2 = require('@radarlabs/s2');

const user1LongLat = [-73.95772933959961, 40.71623280185081];
const user2LongLat = [-73.95927429199219, 40.71629785715124];
const user3LongLat = [-73.99206161499023, 40.688708709249646];

const user1S2 = ["user1", new s2.CellId(new s2.LatLng(user1LongLat[1], user1LongLat[0])).parent(13)];
const user2S2 = ["user2", new s2.CellId(new s2.LatLng(user2LongLat[1], user2LongLat[0])).parent(13)];
const user3S2 = ["user3", new s2.CellId(new s2.LatLng(user3LongLat[1], user3LongLat[0])).parent(13)];

const groups = {};
[user1S2, user2S2, user3S2].forEach(([userId, cellId]) => {
  const group = groups[cellId.token()] || [];
  group.push(userId);
  groups[cellId.token()] = group;
});

console.log(groups); // { '89c2595c': [ 'user1', 'user2' ], '89c25a4c': [ 'user3' ] }
```

Now it's just a simple lookup. S2 has a way to convert a given region into S2 cells, so you could query by a single point or a region.

You can visualize [this on the map here](https://s2.sidewalklabs.com/regioncoverer/?center=40.695295%2C-73.968686&zoom=13&cells=89c2595c%2C89c25a4c).